# How to verify json array using rest assured?

Tags: rest-assured

I have a JSON response:

```
["alice", "jason", "steve", "alex"]
```

then when use rest assured to test:

```
when().
       get("/names").
then().
       body(containsInAnyOrder("alice","jason","steve","alex"));
```

This is not working as I expected, it gives an error:

```
Expected: iterable over ["alice", "jason", "steve", "alex"] in any order
  Actual: ["alice", "jason", "steve", "alex"]
```

Also tried with:

```
when().
       get("/names").
then().
       body(hasItems("alice","jason","steve","alex"));
```

also not working.

How can I verify a simple JSON array in the response?

Answer (score 5):

To save any clicking, you have to supply a redundant string to the body method call:

```
when().
   get("/names").
then().
   body("", hasItems("alice","jason","steve","alex"));
```

Additionally, even if you only have one item in your array, you still have to use `hasItems` rather than `hasItem`. For example:

```
when().
   get("/names").
then().
   body("", hasItems("alice"));
```